# How to config the URL embedded in QR code in device manager

Tags: wso2

I am a newbie to wso2. I just manage to bring up the emm site. But when I try to add my device to the device manager, I find that the QR code generated always has URL with domain localhost. When I look into the logs, it has something like this:

./repository/logs/wso2carbon.log:TID: [-1234] [] [2016-08-22 15:54:05,887]  INFO {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.app.mgt.TomcatJaggeryWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/store].File[/opt/wso2emm-2.0.1/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store]

So, I think I need to config the variable StandardHost to domain I needed. But I can't find a place for that. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the relevent config in the Following file.

```
<EMM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/config/config.json
```

Also you refer the documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/WSO2+Enterprise+Mobility+Manager).